# Analytic for complex function is to _?_ for real function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

As the title, what single word should be filled in the blank in

> Analytic for complex function is to _________ for real function.

?

My first thought is ‘differentiable’. However, then I think differentiability is weaker than analyticity.

Consider the function $f(x):\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\sin x, & x\le 0\\
x, & x>0\\
\end{cases}$$
This real function is differentiable everywhere in its domain.

However, analytic complex functions(*entire functions*) $g(z):\mathbb{C}\mapsto \mathbb{C}$ certainly do not allow piecewise definitions. Therefore, I think differentiability is a weaker condition.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't think you'll get a definitive answer: for complex functions, analytic is equivalent to differentiable. On the other hand, we can also talk about analytic real functions (which in this case is a stronger condition than differentiable or even $C^\infty$.

Comment: Yes, the term I have heard used is "real analytic".